# dropdown onclick on button not able to change the height

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a button, on which hen user clicks dropdown appears, the code for it is like below:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.btn.btn-primary')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowni-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdowni {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdowni-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdowni-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdowni a:hover {
  background-color: #00bfff;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdowni">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdowni-content">
    <a href="#home">Admin</a>
    <a href="#about">Member</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

this gives me something like below image

[image]

i want the size of the content in dropdown to be smaller as it is big right now, i tried setting the height of content and height of the a tag, but nothing is working, when i change the height of a tag, the text is going below, can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code

Comment: After I fixed your snippet, it still does not look anything like your picture

Comment: @mplungjan let me check ur code

Comment: which part did you edit? can you please tell me

Comment: I removed the script and style tags from the snippet so it worked

Comment: i think, the template styles are making the dropdown to show like the image, how can i over ride it?

Comment: this issue in not at your code. this issue come maybe your are using third-party package. just check carefully and change class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code. Apparently, it's ok. Change Padding instead. 
Try:

padding: 5px 10px; //first-one(5px) for top and bottom;
// Second-one(10px) for left and right. Let me know if it works, Good luck.

[image: Change Padding instead]